# Printing from C program

Tags: c, linux, lpr

What is the correct way print file to printer from C -program?

Command `system("lpr /tmp/filename.prn");` generates error `lpr: No file in print request`.

Same command in command line works perfectly.

OS is Debian 9.2, kernel 4.9.0 and cups is version 2.2.1-8

Comment: Out of curiosity, I googled "c printer linux". (I didn't try "print" as you can imagine.) My first hit was [Printing from a C program in linux - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.apps/3VkXE2UlpHQ). I believe you will find an appropriate answer there.

Comment: Many thanks! I found solution following link you provided.
It was a  problem with quoting chars. 
Correct code is: system( "lpr \"/tmp/filename.prn\""); 
"\ does the job.